# jQuery: position div before others when using same class name

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have several divs with the same class name:

```
<div class="cont" id="cont-a">bla bla</div>
<div class="cont" id="cont-b">blo blo</div>
<div class="cont" id="cont-c">bli bli</div>
```

Also have these three links in a nav menu that are supposed to position the relevant div before the others:

```
<a href="#">Show bla bla</a>
<a href="#">Show blo blo</a>
<a href="#">Show bli bli</a>
```

**Question: what jQuery code allows me to position a specific div above the rest based on the link clicked?**

Comment: You want to change the order of the elements based on what was clicked?

Comment: Yes. Each link onlick should position the corresponding div at the top of (before) the others.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9Buuw/). I think it's working as expected.

```
<div id='nav' >
  <a href="#" data-target='#cont-a' >Show bla bla</a>
  <a href="#" data-target='#cont-b' >Show blo blo</a>
  <a href="#" data-target='#cont-c' >Show bli bli</a>    
</div>

<div class="container" >
  <div class="cont" id="cont-a">bla bla</div>
  <div class="cont" id="cont-b">blo blo</div>
  <div class="cont" id="cont-c">bli bli</div>
</div>

$('#nav a').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $container = $('.container')
    target = $(this).data('target');
    $div = $(target)

    $container.prepend($div);
});
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Yes. The issue was lacking a parent container. Didn't really want to create one but it really solves the problem easily.

Answer (score 0):

Create a wrapper div and use `$(selector).append(...)`. So first, you can give the `<a>` tags an `id`. Based on that `id` you can call `$(#[a tag id]).click(function() {put div append here...}`.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
<div>
    <div class="cont" id="cont-a">bla bla</div>
    <div class="cont" id="cont-b">blo blo</div>
    <div class="cont" id="cont-c">bli bli</div>
</div>
```

Change the links to include some identifier:

```
<a href="#" data-target="#cont-a">Show bla bla</a>
<a href="#" data-target="#cont-b">Show blo blo</a>
<a href="#" data-target="#cont-c">Show bli bli</a>
```

Then you can do something like this...

```
$('a').on('click', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $('div.cont.cloned').remove();
    $('div.cont').show();
    var target = $($(this).attr('data-target')),
        clone = target.clone();
    target.hide();
    clone.addClass('cloned');
    clone.prependTo($('div.cont').parent());
});
```

**Edit** This should work properly, and it keeps the items in the same order (except for the one that gets "moved" to the front).

Comment: Use `event.preventDefault()`

Comment: Good catch.  Alternatively, have the href be "javascript:;".

Comment: No, I need to reposition the content because they are always visible.

Comment: Sorry but the code doesn't work: the element is added MULTIPLE times.

Comment: @Antwerp, Are you still seeing it added multiple times?

Answer (score 0):

If all 3 elements are `float:none;` you can use `$("#some_div").css("float","left");`

That will push it in first place.

Comment: They are divs set to display: block;